# What's a word for how long it takes to do something?

Tags: adverbs

I'm trying to track how long it takes to do individual tasks throughout the day.  I'm tracking it in Excel and want a single word for the time it took from beginning to completion to use in the column header. Thanks!

Comment: Duration? If not that word, have you looked up *duration* in a thesaurus or googled for synonyms? Also, you've used the tag "adverbs" (words like *recently*, *thoroughly*, *soon*): are you sure that's what you're after? "How long it takes" sounds like you're after a **noun** (hence my suggestion of *duration*), and nouns or noun phrases are what's normally used for a column header.

Answer (score 4):

I would use:

> **duration**:
>   the length of time that something lasts or continues
>   -- *[Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/duration)*